# Turn date format into a readable one on Sheets and Data Studio

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I have a sheet that is receiving data from another application but the date format comes like this on the cell: 2021-04-09 12:57:51 -0300 and i need this date to be readable by google sheets and data studio as a date format, only with year, month, day. How can I make it using conditions?

I've tried many conditions but no one seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF ( A2:A="",,DATE(
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+?)-"),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "-(..?) "),
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "-(.+?)-"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A10; " ");;1)
```

[image]